# Is it possible to run the Flex SDK compiler on FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, freebsd

I'd like to run the Flex SDK compiler toolchain on our FreeBSD integration server to get around some nasty things like having to check in compiled Flex artifacts (yuck, I know!).

Is this possible? Any success stories? What do I need to do to make it happen?

It's worth noting that we have and use the data visualization components under license, so we'll need support for building with those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive my ignorance here - but does FreeBSD fundamentally differ from other *nix based OS's?

Compiling on *nix servers is supported, and works quite well - including compiling the Data Visualization components.  There are [ant tasks](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html) to assist with this.

The only issues you can run into is executing Flex Unit tests on a headless server, for which you need to [install VNCServer](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Continuous_Integration_Support#Linux).

Apologies if I miss the boat on the FreeBSD vs Standard Linux though.  Never been a strength.

Comment: No, it's not substantially different. Am I to assume, then, that the build tools are completely platform-independent? I was under the impression that there were platform-specific parts, but perhaps that's just for the IDE.

Comment: Yeah - that's the IDE only.  There's an Alpha quality linux version of the IDE, but Adobe stopped development on that a while back.  The SDK will build (and is often built) on *nix servers